# Doing prediction with RNN on Sequential data in keras

Tags: python, keras, deep-learning, prediction

I'm new to the ML and I was following this [tutorial](https://pythonprogramming.net/crypto-rnn-model-deep-learning-python-tensorflow-keras/) which teaches how to do cryptocurrency predictions based on some futures.

My code to do the prediction:

```
model = load_model("Path//myModel.model")

ready_x = preprocess_df(main_df) # the function returns array of price sequences and targets (0-buy,1-sells): return np.array(X), y 
predictions = []

for x in ready_x:
 l_p = model.predict_classes(x) #error occurs on this line
 predictions.append(l_p[0])
plot_prediction(main_df, predictions)
```

But i got the below error:

> ValueError: Error when checking input: expected lstm_input to have 3
>   dimensions, but got array with shape (69188, 1)

I don't really get the idea of this error, It's literally my second project on ML after famous cats and dogs classification. So don't have much experience for debugging, I did learn the theory first, about neurons and the relationships between them but still It's really difficult to apply that knowledge to the real project. So the idea of this project is to predict the future price, 3 minute into the future, based on the last 60 minute prices (trained on that).
The model looks like this:

```
model = Sequential()
model.add(LSTM(128, input_shape=(train_x.shape[1:]),return_sequences=True))
model.add(Dropout(0.2))
model.add(BatchNormalization())

model.add(LSTM(128, return_sequences=True))
model.add(Dropout(0.1))
model.add(BatchNormalization())

model.add(LSTM(128))
model.add(Dropout(0.2))
model.add(BatchNormalization())

model.add(Dense(32, activation="relu"))
model.add(Dropout(0.2))

model.add(Dense(2, activation="softmax"))

opt = tf.keras.optimizers.Adam(lr=0.001, decay=1e-6)
```

[image: model.summary()]

`main_df` is a data frame and consists of:

[image]
My question is, how i should I feed the model with correct data input to do this prediction?

**EDIT:**
`preprocess` function:

```
def preprocess_df(df):
    #scalling
    df = df.drop('future', 1)

    for col in df.columns:
        if col!= "target":
            df[col] = df[col].pct_change() # normalizes the data
            df.dropna(inplace=True)
            df[col] = preprocessing.scale(df[col].values) #scale the data between 0-1

    df.dropna(inplace=True)

    sequential_data = []
    prev_days = deque(maxlen=SEQ_LEN)

    for i in df.values:
        prev_days.append([n for n in i[:-1]]) # append each column and not taking a target
        if len(prev_days) == SEQ_LEN:
            sequential_data.append([np.array(prev_days), i[-1]])

    random.shuffle(sequential_data)

    # BALANCING THE DATA
    buys = []
    sells = []

    for seq, target in sequential_data:
        if target == 0:
            sells.append([seq, target])
        elif target == 1:
            buys.append([seq, target])

    random.shuffle(buys)
    random.shuffle(sells)

    lower = min(len(buys), len(sells))

    buys = buys[:lower]
    sells = sells[:lower]

    sequential_data = buys + sells
    random.shuffle(sequential_data)

    X = []
    y = []

    for seq, target in sequential_data:
        X.append(seq)
        y.append(target)

    return np.array(X), y
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

LSTM expects inputs shaped `(batch_size, timesteps, channels)`; in your case, `timesteps=60`, and `channels=128`. `batch_size` is how many samples you're feeding at once, per fit / prediction.

Your error indicates preprocessing flaws:

- Rows of your DataFrame, based on index name `time`, would fill dim 1 of `x` -> `timesteps`
- Columns are usually features, and would fill dim 2 of `x` -> `channels`
- dim 0 is the samples dimension; a "sample" is an independent observation - depending on how your data is formatted, one file could be one sample, or contain multiple

Once accounting for above:

- `print(x.shape)` should read `(N, 60, 128)`, where `N` is the number of samples, `>= 1`
- Since you're iterating over `ready_x`, `x` will slice `ready_x` along its dim 0 - so `print(ready_x.shape)` should read `(M, N, 60, 128)`, where `M >= 1`; it's the "batches" dimension, each slice being 1 batch.

As basic debugging: insert `print(item.shape)` throughout your preprocessing code, where `item` is an array, DataFrame, etc. - to see how shapes change throughout various steps. Ensure that there is a step which gives `128` on the last dimension, and `60` on second-to-last.

Comment: I tried print(ready_x.shape) and get the error : AttributeError: 'tuple' object has no attribute 'shape'

Comment: also tired:  for x in ready_x:
                      print(x.shape)                                                         and got the error: AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'shape'

Comment: I still don't get it man, could i contact you via email or smth to send you full code to see if you can. Would appreciate it

Comment: @casper StackOverflow isn't for debugging your entire program - try narrowing the problem. From your description it seems like you'll have plenty of such bugs, so the best idea may be starting with a simpler example or otherwise learning more Python. Regardless, for this particular error, sounds like there are multiple lists in `ready_x`, so you could try `x = np.asarray(x)`, and then print shape.

Comment: I got it, I've updated a question and added the preproces fucntion, could you take a glance at it please and maybe u see smth

Comment: @casper Run [this](https://pastebin.com/PyNLWjg4), link me its output

Comment: I ran ur code, here is a [link](https://pastebin.com/xAkZLNpg)

Comment: [Full code](https://pastebin.com/A9TSM6kz) if needed. plus  [csv file content image](https://pasteboard.co/IXlK60C.png)

Comment: I've uploaded one of the csv files to [this link](https://ufile.io/37cbatwc) as well, for downloading